# How to map a non-domain class in a hasMany association using GORM?

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm, has-many, complextype

I have a domain class which has a hasMany association to the java.awt.Rectangle class, a complex type which isn't a part of my domain model.

Altho Gorm mapped a single Rectangle to a blob, it doesn't know how to map a list of rectangles automatically.

Gorm docs show how to do custom mapping of hasMany associations (joinTable:) and also custom mapping of single non-domain complex classes (type:). However I can't find anywhere an example where ***domain** hasMany **complex class***. The closest I got to any help was a domain class having a list of Strings... which didn't helped that much.

Here is my last try to solve it:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle

class MyDomainClass {
    static hasMany = [figures:Rectangle]

    static mapping = {
        figures joinTable: [name: 'my_domain_class_figures',
                          key: 'my_domain_class_id',
                          column: "figure",
                          sqlType: "blob"]
    }
}
```

Here is the important part of the error thrown by DbmGormDiff:

> nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Missing type or column for column[figure] on domain[MyDomainClass] referencing[java.awt.Rectangle]

Another try that I did managed to pass by DbmGormDiff and the table generated look good, having the DomainClass FK and a blob.

```
static mapping = {
    figures joinTable: [name: 'my_domain_class_figures',
                      key: 'my_domain_class_id',
                      column: "figure"]
    figures type: "blob"
}
```

Yet, at object.save() I get this exception

> java.awt.Rectangle cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob

Weirdly, if I my domain class had only one Rectangle (e.g.: *Rectangle figure* instead of *hasMany: [figures: Rectangle]*) the auto-mapping would transform Rectangle into a blob.

Comment: Have you tried to create a domain class which extends the Rectangle (with no added fields) and put the has many on that class ?

Comment: I believe that this will work, wrapping Rectangle with a domain class, but I rather not to that. Feels like bad programming just to workaround something I don't know how to do.